Machine Learning Algorithm for identifying the factors contributing to academic performance of students
I have a dataset with several qualitative and quantitative attributes, including age, location (longitude, latitude), city, parent occupation, family size, GPA etc. My task is to find the attributes/factors that contribute the highest towards the academic performance of the students. Which machine learning algorithm is the most suitable for this task?
A friend suggested using clustering algorithm that can segment the students into different performance groups, but I think that will not solve my problem.

You’re looking for an algorithm with identifies the explained variance of each feature.  The first to my mind was Principal Component Analysis.  But the more I thought about it, I personally am more comfortable with decision trees and their interpretability will often give a similar insight.
